# Get JS variable inside of game loop

Tags: javascript

A popular online browser-based game, [Shellshock](https://shellshock.io/), is written entirely in javascript. There is a game loop that is always running in a function called `setUpSocket` (which restarts the game if called) and inside of that loop is a variable which controls the entire game. If you access it, you will have access to all game objects.

My goal is to use javascript (my own script) to get this object and use it comunicate with some software and report player's statuses, etc. This variable is encased within a while loop, and the only way to access it is to add a breakpoint, then define a window scope variable with it's value.

Here's what I've discovered:
If you `watch` the variable in the chrome developer console, the variable is only ever set while the code has been frozen by the breakpoint I put in (https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2Lwn.jpg) and  at all other times it is invalid/undefined.

Is there a way to (at the start of the function) use javascript to get this variable every frame (setInterval) so I can use it's data?
How can I do this without manully setting a breakpoint?

(extra: Game is in Javascript, on webgl2 canvas)

Comment: You shouldn't do this. Check if they have a public API that you can call to get game data. They could change their implementation of how they storing the game data at any point and break what you've done.

Comment: I am not concerned about them changing how they store their data, and how the game works. I did check for an API, but they do not have one.

Comment: Code outside a function cannot access local variables within the function. The debugger is special, since it's built into the implementation.

Comment: You could write a script that rewrites their script on the fly (when it is loaded, before it is being run) so that you would have access to the variable (basically inserting a hook function call).

Comment: @bergi The only issue is that this script is 130,000 lines, and it would crash my browser.

Comment: @Paulpro This script is going to be run through the extension tamper monkey (to run while page is loaded). I could do it manually then access it, but it would take a bit.

Comment: A browser (Chrome/Firefox) extension would do it. Example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Modify_a_web_page Otherwise you can't achieve exactly what you are trying to do via server-side scripting.